# How does roughening a surface help with Reynolds number matching?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have a research paper describing a wind tunnel test conducted on a small scale model of a mast.

It is said:

> Considering the similarity of the Reynolds number, the surface of the cylinder part needed to be properly roughened. In this research, sandpaper was used to cover the surface in order to simulate the high Reynolds number effects on the real structure.

The paper does not elaborate why the Reynolds number couldn't be matched, but I understand that is a common problem with wind tests.

What I'm curious though, what effects of the high Reynolds number does the sandpaper simulate? Reynolds number is a property of the flow, not the object in the flow, right? So why could the roughening make the test more accurate?

What comes to mind is that the drag coefficient probably increases with a rougher surface..

Comment: Could you share a link to the research paper?

Comment: @Nick Unfortunately I cannot, it is a print copy in my native language and not available online.